# Multi language site with "english only" backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm building an app on Rails 3.1. The frontend will have 5 languages, while the backend will be only in English.

The admin will be able to create objects on the backend using [globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) to specify attribute translations. Here a part of the controller to create a product:

```
class Admin::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_language
  after_filter :set_back_to_default_language

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.create(params[:product])
    if @product.errors.empty?
      redirect_to admin_product_path(@product)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  private
  def set_language
    I18n.locale = :it
  end

  def set_back_to_default_language
    I18n.locale = :en
  end
end
```

That will create a product with the italian attributes setup. But if an attribute is required the output of:

```
<%= @product.errors[:title] %>
```

will be

```
translation missing: it.activerecord.errors.models.product.attributes.title.blank
```

Do you know a way to set the attributes in the right language having the validations always in the default language? I can't use `I18n.default_locale = :en` because in the frontend I have other form and the validation strings should be localized.

Answer (score 1):

Use [batch_translations](https://github.com/fidel/batch_translations). It's a little plugin, not a gem unfortunately. But I used it in a project recently and it worked just fine. I think you can easily adapt it to your needs.